# Refactor overheaded T-SQL query

Tags: sql-server, performance, t-sql, refactoring

Is there a way to refactor this query so it no longer makes so many GetRemainingAmount(@Id) function calls? I tried naming it in select block e.g. **Amount** and then use it in Where and Group it's compilation error.

```
 SELECT SomeAccountId ,
        GetRemainingAmount(@Id) ,
        Iso
 FROM   Accounts
 WHERE  GetRemainingAmount(@Id) > 0
 GROUP BY SomeAccountId ,
        GetRemainingAmount(@Id) ,
        Iso
```

Comment: Paste code of `GetRemainingAmount()`

Comment: CROSS APPLY in the SELECT will give the result in a field you can then use in the WHERE/GROUP BY; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3196851/where-clause-on-a-column-thats-a-result-of-a-udf

Comment: Paste? won't change anything, GetRemainingAmount is time consuming function and I want to avoid those duplicated calls to it.

Comment: Scalar UDFs in the `WHERE` clause is an anti pattern. You have no other predicates so it will always evaluate it for every row in `Accounts`. If you show us the code for it we might suggest an alternative.

Comment: Martin Smith makes the most important point. You can reduce the number of times you have to type that code but the where clause will only eliminate rows after running that function for all of them. It is impossible to know if the amount is greater than 0 until you calculate the amount on each row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always do something like this, using a CTE (Common Table Expression) to isolate that call and do it only once:

```
;WITH CTE AS 
(
   SELECT 
      SomeAccountId,
      RemainingAmount = GetRemainingAmount(@Id),
      Iso
   FROM   
      Accounts 
)
SELECT
    SomeAccountId, RemainingAmount, Iso
FROM 
    CTE
WHERE  
    RemainingAmount > 0
GROUP BY 
    SomeAccountId,
    RemainingAmount,
    Iso
```

But quite honestly, if there's no aggregate function like `SUM` or `AVG` involved, I don't see the point of the `GROUP BY` clause in the first place ....

Comment: The `GROUP BY` could still be eliminating duplicates, but it does appear it could be replaced by `DISTINCT`.

Answer (score 1):

Could use a distinct to eliminate the GROUP BY

```
SELECT  distinct 
        SomeAccountId ,
        GetRemainingAmount(@Id) ,
        Iso
 FROM   Accounts
 WHERE  GetRemainingAmount(@Id) > 0
```

Answer (score 1):

Or you can derive it:

```
select 
    SomeAccountId,
    RemainingAmount,
    Iso
from (
    SELECT 
        SomeAccountId,
        GetRemainingAmount(@Id) as RemainingAmount,
        Iso
    FROM Accounts
) _Data
WHERE RemainingAmount > 0
GROUP BY 
    SomeAccountId,
    RemainingAmount,
    Iso
```